# ASP.NET MVC 4 Server Validations wont appear on turning Javascript Off

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Have given all sorts of validations like [Required], [StringLength] etc..etc.. in my model class, but these server side validation messages only appear when Javascript is turned on in the browser.

On disabling Javascript, none of these server side validations seem to work, i cant figure out why it is happening like this.

Can someone guide me on this issue.

Comment: Could you put your controller, view and class code please?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can ask if the Model you are posting is valid with:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // some persistence logic
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Error("there were some errors in your form.");

    return View(model);
}
```

To be clear, this behaviour server side is completely unaffected by the client's javascript setting. The client's setting only has the ability to allow or prevent form submission to your controller.

Comment: The code you have shown above, i have given exactly like that. I have a model class as well as a viewModel for that model class. The  validations have been given in the viewModel, but still it does not seem to work.

Comment: I would remove the model class from the problem and just work with your ViewModel until you are fixed. The validation is in the right place on the view model and the action method should take the one ViewModel argument.

Comment: I figured the error out. It was with the ViewModel part. Thank You for Your help ..:)